# Problem with mutating in dplyr a big function with nested functions using the case_when in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a function that computes the binomial tree of call or put option found [here](https://financetrain.com/binomial-option-pricing-model-in-r).I made them all one one function that contain all the other functions described in the link such as :

```
Binomial_Call = function(S0, K, r, Ti, sigma,N) {
  delta_t=Ti/N
  
  q_prob = function(r, delta_t, sigma) {
    u = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
    d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
    return((exp(r*delta_t) - d)/(u-d))
  }
  q = q_prob(r=r, delta_t=delta_t, sigma=sigma)
  build_stock_tree = function(S0, sigma, delta_t, N) {
    tree = matrix(0, nrow=N+1, ncol=N+1)
    U = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
    D = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
    for (i in 1:(N+1)) {
      for (j in 1:i) {
        tree[i, j] = S0 * U^(j-1) * D^((i-1)-(j-1))
      }  }
    return(tree)
  }
  tree = build_stock_tree(S0=S0, sigma=sigma, delta_t=delta_t, N=N)
  value_binomial_option = function(tree, sigma, delta_t, r, K) {
    q_prob = function(r, delta_t, sigma) {
      u = exp(sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
      d = exp(-sigma*sqrt(delta_t))
      return((exp(r*delta_t) - d)/(u-d))
    }
    q = q_prob(r, delta_t, sigma)
    option_tree = matrix(0, nrow=nrow(tree), ncol=ncol(tree))
    option_tree[nrow(option_tree),] = pmax(tree[nrow(tree),] - K, 0)
    for (i in (nrow(tree)-1):1) {
      for(j in 1:i) {
        option_tree[i,j]=((1-q)*option_tree[i+1,j] + q*option_tree[i+1,j+1])/exp(r*delta_t)
      }
    }
    return(option_tree)
  }
  option = value_binomial_option(tree, sigma=sigma, delta_t=Ti/N, r=r, K=K)
  #return(list(q=q, stock=tree, option=option, price=option[1,1]))
  price=option[1,1]
  print(price)
}
```

Now I have a data frame :

```
stock   = rep(42,4)
strike  = rep(40,4)
risk    = rep(0.1)
time    = rep(0.25)
sigma   = rep(0.2)
N       = rep(60,4)
option  = c(rep(c("C","P"),2)) 
Asset   = c(rep("FTSE",2),"FACEBOOK","TWITTER")
data = tibble(stock,strike,risk,time,sigma,N,option,Asset);data
 A tibble: 4 × 8
  stock strike  risk  time sigma     N option Asset   
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   
1    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 C      FTSE    
2    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 P      FTSE    
3    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 C      FACEBOOK
4    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 P      TWITTER
```

When I try to implement the function in mutate:

```
data%>%
  mutate(price = case_when(Asset != "FTSE" & option == "C" ~ Binomial_Call(stock,strike,risk,time,sigma,N)))
```

I receive the following error:

Error in `mutate()`:

```
! Problem while computing `price = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `tree[i, j] <- S0 * U^(j - 1) * D^((i - 1) - (j - 1))`:
! number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
Problem while computing `price = case_when(...)`.
ℹ numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
```

why ? Why Is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function seems to be not vectorized.  So we may use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   rowwise %>%
    mutate(price = case_when(Asset != "FTSE" & option == "C" ~
       Binomial_Call(stock,strike,risk,time,sigma,N))) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  stock strike  risk  time sigma     N option Asset    price
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
1    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 C      FTSE     NA   
2    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 P      FTSE     NA   
3    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 C      FACEBOOK  3.53
4    42     40   0.1  0.25   0.2    60 P      TWITTER  NA
```

Comment: thank you very much.That solves it.But if I wanted to show the resulted number with 6 decimal places ?

Comment: when I run it before the reported output as your R reported me four single vectors with the same value (the output vale).Why is that ? How can I avoid it ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson  It is a tibble print format.  If you extract the output `price` it should have the precision i.e. if i pull the column `..%>% pull(price)
[1]      NA      NA 3.52814      NA`

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson regarding your second comment .  The values `Binomial_Call(stock,strike,risk,time,sigma,N)` are all the same for the data you showed.  thus it gives the same output

Comment: can we chat ? I don't know how we chat

Comment: I solved it.It was because the print at the end of the function.I has to change it to return

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson sorry, I did change that when I tested.  Forgot to tell you.  Glad that it worked.  I was checking on the chat room to invite you.